# What are the possible solution to hide the field from the child publication

Tags: tridion

We have a main schema which are using for generic content at many places and across blueprint for many websites(markets).

Now one of the website(market) wants one extra field but all other do not wants to see this in their publications.

I suggested to rename the fields for all other markets like (Not in use) but they are not agreeing on this as well.

What are the possible solution to hide the field from the child publication?

Comment: Are the field build up dynamically? If not, you could try to reaorganize it that way meaning that when another market wants a custom field you can load it dynamically. My point of view is always reusabillity takes you longer in the beginning saves you time at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, What do mean by dynamically? sorry I do not have idea about this.

Comment: i was talking about some sort of management system, which gives you the option to maybe select (custom)fields which you want to have on your schema. example: Market A : fields 1,2,3  Market B: field 2,4,8

Comment: Tridion 2009 but we are planning to upgrade to 2011 SP1 soon...

Comment: @JonathanRomer Sorry not sure how it is possible. Do you have reference from where I can get more detail on this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the full context it is hard to give an advise. But in general I would not  recommend to hide fields (even though it's possible with a GUI extension in 2011 and with some hacking in 2009). I think Tridion offers plenty of options to solve the puzzle out of the box. For example:

1. Isolate the common fields into an embedded schema and set up separate content schemas for market A and market B which reuse the common fields
2. Isolate the different fields into content schemas for market A and market B and create a component link field in the original schema which links to those specific schemas.

With security on folders you can limit access to the market-specific schemas.

Comment: Thanks @Quirijn, the main issue is schema is already in use at thousand of places. We can try GUI extn.

Comment: In that case I would go for Nickoli's suggestion.

Comment: Hiding/Showing fields is not an extension point in the GUI. It can be done but it requires dom manipulation or fieldBuilder (Anguila obj) modification when the "Content" tab is loaded. I have done this before, and I still think the best approach, based on these comments, is Nick's. Train the users, they should know what to fill in and what not. You might want to group all those fields together too.

Comment: @JaimeSantosAlcón Could you please share some sample code with me? Our stakeholders do not want to see few fields at all.

Comment: I don't have any example, but this is what you'll need the following:

Add your js extension when the "Content" tab is loaded. You might need to remove the existing one and add yours (which would be a replica of the Content one) that hooks up to the fieldBuilder and checks the field names (so you can determine which ones to hide) and then you have to hide them.

As Nick mention this fields should be optional...
Another thing you might want to disable is the "Source" tab.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is to not hide the field.  Simply add the new field as non-mandatory and in its description clearly call out that it's only applicable for Market B such that the other markets know not to use it.  This is simple, requires no effort and is a maintenance free solution.  Otherwise a GUI extension is your best bet.

Comment: I agree with Nickoli, It might mean some discussions with your users to convince them to bear this extra field. But it's probably the best solution.